# How many element can List have to work effectively

Tags: development

I must do a project with 360000 element's on list. Are the list can geret with it ? How make fast a queryes on the project ? Where shall I put indexes, and should I made a orderby on Query CAML?

After move from local serv, to production serv a aplication is very slow.

Comment: 360,000 isn't a lot. Just make sure you use paging.

Comment: Ok, but how use a pagging in asp calendar, and lists.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking if a list can handle 360,000 items/rows? Don't do it. SharePoint is happy around a few hundred items, maybe a thousand or two. When you hit 3+ thousand rows bad things happen, performance drops, users get mad, SharePoint get's a bad name, and then you're out of a job. ;)

If you know you're going to be working with 360K items, move your data into a separate SQL database, and then use BDC to consume (and CRUD) the list. You'll be happiest in this scenario.

Comment: Have You got any link about this conection ? How to put then elements to sharepoint lists and Info path

Comment: I don't cnow hav to corelate BDC with InfoPath. I must do some thinks by InfoPath

Answer (score 2):

A SharePoint 2010 list can contain up to 50 million items. You can mange this amount of data using indexes, filtered views, throttling...

This [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010377496.aspx) will provide you with information on how to manage list and libraries with many items.

To enhance performance when working with large lists in code you can specify what fields are returned, the row limit and use pagination. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557257.aspx) MSDN page has an example.

Comment: I want to do it in the ASP callendar, for a lot of person. Maybe I should done it by erson, and don't show a lot of person, only one person and, next change it, and change it a lot of times

Comment: For example you can display for each person a view containig 20 items and add a pager. When the user clicks on it a query will be executed and another 20 items will be returned from the server. So you will get 20 items per server call. This is done using pagination.

Comment: In calendar pagging are done by month, but how done a pagging in calendar using CAML?

Comment: There is a paging example at the end of the article referenced by the second link in my response.