# Large list more then 300 000 Elements How to write Fast CAML Queries

Tags: development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many element can List have to work effectively](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51180/how-many-element-can-list-have-to-work-effectively)

I have go a Question. How write effectively CAML Queries to fast read Queriess and how add a pagging to the ASP Calendar. Please Help. I must write 360 000 elements on one list.

Comment: http://blog.solanite.com/keith/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15 Take a read up on optimising list performance here. From this you should be able to design the best way from your knowledge of the data.

Comment: Also consider using the Search API - pulling stuff out the search index is way faster than reading from lists using CAML.

Comment: Also, 360k items isn't that many. SharePoint 'officially' supports millions of items in a list.

Comment: Can You James Love give a link for Search API?

Comment: I know its not much, but how to corelare pagging with ASP Calendar to work fast ?

Comment: Is this for the same code as I helped you with before, Grzegorz Z?

Comment: Yes for ASP Calendar :) You helped me with vacation of Workers :) Now I need to add pagging for calendar, because if the elements are more then 90 000 the Ajaks Update panel with the Calendar is loging about 5 minutes and more. So i must add pagging to do it fasters. Paging after workers for example. If I chose a Worker from drop down list it schould sshow me only data for this worker. All Drop Down List and ASP Calendar are in Update Panel. Please help.

Comment: This is basically the same question as before with the addition of the calendar paging question. If you still need help with the calendar, please ask a new specific question, rather than ask two questions in one. Thanks.

Comment: But here is more infos about a problem. Why are You Closed this question ? :(